# Descriptive vs Injunctive statement

Tags: verbs, mood

"Residents in an efficient household take a five-minute shower per person per day"-- I think it is a descriptive statement. I want to know its injunctive counterpart.

Comment: It should be _**a** five-minute shower_. The article is necessary for the idiom _take a shower_, and the hyphen should connect _five_ and _minute_, not _minute_ and _shower_. It has the form of a statement, but it could function as an impositive in many contexts. The key power word is _efficient_; whoever defines that word successfully governs the injunctions expressed here.

Comment: @John: oops, you're right. The question arrived untagged and I didn't proof read well enough. Let's put that right, at least...

Answer (score 1):

English doesn't have an injunctive mood: rather than inflection, it changes the verb entirely.

The injunction to do something is indicated by the modal verb *must* or its broad equivalent *is/are to*

> Residents in an efficient household **must take** a five-minute shower per person per day
> Residents in an efficient household **are to take** a five-minute shower per person per day

Closely related is *have to,* which is descriptive but incorporates the necessity of the action:

> Residents in an efficient household **have to take** a five-minute shower per person per day

Comment: 'Residents in efficient households: each take a five-minute shower every day!' is a hortative statement reminiscent of UK Government public information / advice broadcasts of the mid-20th century.